# Binary Search recursive step list passing

Tags: python

The list I am passing to my recursive function is not passing its value. It should pass [5, 9, 12]. However, [] is being passed on the first step of recursion. Therefore, I am unable to get the middle index (I get 0) and I try to index and empty list with 0 and my code breaks with:

```
  File "C:\Users\wesch\Desktop\bs.py", line 5, in search
    currentMiddleValue = nums[currentMiddleIndex]
  File "C:\Users\wesch\Desktop\bs.py", line 10, in search
    return self.search(nums[currentMiddleIndex:len(nums)], target)
  File "C:\Users\wesch\Desktop\bs.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(test.search([-1,0,3,5,9,12], 9))
```

error.

Code:

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: list, target: int) -> int:
        #nums = nums[currentMiddleIndex:len(nums)]
        currentMiddleIndex = int((len(nums)) // 2)
        currentMiddleValue = nums[currentMiddleIndex]
        nums = nums[currentMiddleIndex:len(nums)]
        if currentMiddleValue == target:
            return nums.index(currentMiddleValue)
        elif currentMiddleValue < target:
            return self.search(nums[currentMiddleIndex:len(nums)], target)
        elif currentMiddleIndex == 0:
            return -1
        else: 
            return self.search(nums[0:currentMiddleIndex], target)
test = Solution()
print(test.search([-1,0,3,5,9,12], 9))
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code by setting breakpoints and using the debugger?

Comment: Why are you using `nums.index()`. This will perform a linear search and basically remove any performance benefit it the number happens to be the middle one. You already know the index

Comment: Another issue is that if figure out the number is in the right half you return the index in the right half, which will not be equal to the length of the list itself. You need to add the length of the left half and middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is here:

```
nums = nums[currentMiddleIndex:len(nums)]
```

you are changing nums, now it's length is only half of what it was.

Then you use:

```
return self.search(nums[currentMiddleIndex:len(nums)], target)
```

but now, the "num" has already been truncated and it's length is *already* half of what it was, and you are truncating it again, starting from the halfway index from before truncation, which is now actually equal to the length of the array.

You shouldn't truncate your array with `nums = nums[currentMiddleIndex:len(nums)]` or if you do keep in mind that you no longer have the full array, but only the second half of it

There are other problems in your code though

Comment: That's just one of the multiple problems

Comment: true but that's why he's getting an empty array

Comment: Thanks for answering the question I was asking!